# How to give the value in data jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I now am working with my project. I have the problem with the data. I have knowledge on jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){         
        var price = $(this).val();          
        add_payment_value(price);     
    });  
});  
function add_payment_value(price){     
// here you can use $.ajax function to add your 'price value' to your cart     
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",    
        url: "add_payment.php", 
        // file where you can add price to your database   
        data: "",    
        success: function(){} // return something on success
    });
}
```

I have 4 values which is stored in radio buttons ordered `4, 6.5, 8, 11`. My question is how to write the values in data and `var price = $(this).val();`? Can anyone fill this? I gave some value but that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change the add_payment_value function to accept a name and then uaw the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var price = $(this).attr("value");
    var name =  $(this).attr("name");
    add_payment_value(price, name);
    });
});

function add_payment_value(price, name){
    // here you can use $.ajax function to add your 'price value' to your cart 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_payment.php", // file where you can add price to your database
        data: name + "=" + price,
        success: function(){} // return something on success 
    });

}
```

Another alternative is to format the data string in the click handler and send it to add_payment_value function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    var price = $(this).attr("value");
    var name =  $(this).attr("name");
    add_payment_value(name + "=" + price);
    });
});

function add_payment_value(priceData){
    // here you can use $.ajax function to add your 'price value' to your cart 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add_payment.php", // file where you can add price to your database
        data: priceData,
        success: function(){} // return something on success 
    });

}
```

Comment: You're probably better off passing a key/value pairs object to the data parameter for jQuery to take care of the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

use radio button id like ("#rb1").value instead of this.